# Understanding Python bitwise, arithmetic, and boolean operators

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and not able to understand this. Can someone help break down the statement for me?

Both n and parity are integers

```
n += parity != n & 1
```

Comment: What are `n` and `parity` defined as?

Comment: Can we get some context for this code?  Do you have a sense of what type of variables n and parity are?

Comment: both n and parity are integers

Comment: please let me know if any other details are required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression is evaluated as `n += (parity != (n & 1))`, and the results are:

- `n & 1` is a *bitmask*, it masks the integer `n` down to the least-significant bit. If `n` is odd, it will be `1`, if it is even, that bit will be `0`.
- `parity != 0` or `parity != 1` produces a *boolean* result, `True` or `False`, signalling if `parity` was not equal to the `0` or `1` on the right.
- The resulting `True` or `False` is added up to `n`, as if you did `n = n + True` or `n = n + False`. The Python boolean type is a *subclass* of `int` and `False` has an integer value of `0` and `True` a value of `1`.

The code, in essence, is adding `0` or `1` to `n` based on the value of `parity` and if `n` is currently even or odd.

A short demo may illustrate this better.

First, `n & 1` producing `0` or `1`:

```
>>> n = 10  # even
>>> bin(n)  # the binary representation of 10
'0b1010'
>>> n & 1   # should be 0, as the last bit is 0
0
>>> n = 11  # odd
>>> bin(n)  # the binary representation of 11
'0b1011'
>>> n & 1   # should be 1, as the last bit is 1
1
```

Next, the `parity != 0` or `parity != 1` part; note that I assume `parity` is limited to `0` or `1`, it really doesn't make sense for it to have other values:

```
>>> parity = 0
>>> parity != 1
True
>>> parity != 0
False
>>> parity = 1
>>> parity != 1
False
>>> parity != 0
True
```

Last, that booleans are integers:

```
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> int(True)
1
>>> 10 + True
11
>>> 10 + False
10
```

The formula looks like it is calculating a [*CRC checksum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Answer (score 0):

Lets break this down:

```
(n += (parity != (n & 1)))
```

`(n & 1)` this is bitmask, and takes the value of the smallest (least significant bit) of `n`.

`parity !=` this is true if `parity` is different from the result of `(n & 1)`

`n +=` this increments `n` by whatever value the rest of the line returns.

```
n    parity    output(increment of n)
0      1         1
1      1         0
1      0         1
0      0         0
```

From the above table you can see that it functions like an XOR of n's LSB and parity.

Notes: Usually parity is the oddness(1) or evenness(0) of a data packet.

Hope this helps! Enjoy.